# Trouble updating a record with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

With a class and table definition looking like this:

```
case class Group(
  id: Long = -1,
  id_parent: Long = -1,
  label: String = "",
  description: String = "")

  object Groups extends Table[Group]("GROUPS") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def id_parent = column[Long]("ID_PARENT")
    def label = column[String]("LABEL")
    def description = column[String]("DESC")
    def * = id ~ id_parent ~ label ~ design <> (Group, Group.unapply _)
    def autoInc = id_parent ~ label ~ design returning id into {
      case ((_, _, _), id) => id
    }
  }
```

To update a record, I can do this:

```
  def updateGroup(id: Long) = Groups.where(_.id === id)

  def updateGroup(g: Group)(implicit session: Session) = updateGroup(g.id).update(g)
```

But I can't get updates to work using for expressions:

```
  val findGById = for {
    id <- Parameters[Long]
    g <- Groups; if g.id === id
  } yield g

  def updateGroupX(g: Group)(implicit session: Session) = findGById(g.id).update(g)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
Error: value update is not a member of scala.slick.jdbc.MutatingUnitInvoker[com.exp.Group]
```

I'm obviously missing something in [the documentation.](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html#updating)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `update` method is supplied by the type [`UpdateInvoker`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.driver.BasicInvokerComponent$UpdateInvoker). An instance of that type can be implicitly created from a `Query` by the methods `productQueryToUpdateInvoker` and/or `tableQueryToUpdateInvoker` (found in the [`BasicProfile`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.driver.BasicProfile$Implicits)), if they are in scope.

Now the type of your `findById` method is not a `Query` but a `BasicQueryTemplate[Long, Group]`. Looking at the docs, I can find no way from a `BasicQueryTemplate` (which is a subtype of `StatementInvoker`) to an `UpdateInvoker`, neither implicit nor explicit. Thinking about it, that makes kinda sense to me, since I understand a query template (invoker) to be something that has already been "compiled" from an abstract syntax tree (`Query`) to a prepared statement rather early, before parameterization, whereas an update invoker can only be built from an abstract syntax tree, i.e. a `Query` object, because it needs to analyze the query and extract its parameters/columns. At least that's the way it appears to work at present.

With that in mind, a possible solution unfolds:

```
def findGById(id: Long) = for {
  g <- Groups; if g.id === id
} yield g

def updateGroupX(g: Group)(implicit session: Session) = findGById(g.id).update(g)
```

Where `findById(id: Long)` has the type `Query[Groups, Group]` which is converted by `productQueryToUpdateInvoker` to an `UpdateInvoker[Group]` on which the `update` method can finally be called.

Hope this helped.

Comment: A good explanation of why it doesn't work, but it seems to me that it's a [limitation of the Slick framework](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/102). The fact that BasicQueryTemplate is not as rich as Query, seems to make it impossible to cache queries that have parameters and sortBy or groupBy.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to http://madnessoftechnology.blogspot.ru/2013/01/database-record-updates-with-slick-in.html

I stuck with the updating today, and this blog post helped me much. Also refer to the first comment under the post.